# Junit class failing after ACS Commons version upgrade to 5.3.4

Tags: aem

I upgraded ACS Commons version from 5.0.6 to 5.3.4 in my project and now can see most of the test classes failing with below error

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter [io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit5.AemContext arg0] in method [void com.test.test.core.filters.LoggingFilterTest.doFilter(io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit5.AemContext) throws java.io.IOException,javax.servlet.ServletException]: Could not create io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit5.ResourceResolverMockAemContext instance.

at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:232)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:176)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:137)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:118)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
a


Caused by: org.reflections.ReflectionsException: Scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner was not configured
at org.reflections.Store.get(Store.java:39)
at org.reflections.Store.get(Store.java:61)
at org.reflections.Store.get(Store.java:46)
```

Please find below my test class. I am using JUnit version as below

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.wcm</groupId>
<artifactId>io.wcm.testing.aem-mock.junit5</artifactId>
<version>4.0.4</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Attaching the class below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.servlet.MockRequestPathInfo;
import org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.servlet.MockSlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.servlet.MockSlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Disabled;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

import io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit5.AemContext;
import io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit5.AemContextExtension;
import uk.org.lidalia.slf4jext.Level;
import uk.org.lidalia.slf4jtest.LoggingEvent;
import uk.org.lidalia.slf4jtest.TestLogger;
import uk.org.lidalia.slf4jtest.TestLoggerFactory;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

@ExtendWith(AemContextExtension.class)
class LoggingFilterTest {

    private LoggingFilter fixture = new LoggingFilter();

    private TestLogger logger = TestLoggerFactory.getTestLogger(fixture.getClass());

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        TestLoggerFactory.clear();
    }


    @Test
    void doFilter(AemContext context) throws IOException, ServletException {
        MockSlingHttpServletRequest request = context.request();
        MockSlingHttpServletResponse response = context.response();

        MockRequestPathInfo requestPathInfo = (MockRequestPathInfo) request.getRequestPathInfo();
        requestPathInfo.setResourcePath("/content/test");
        requestPathInfo.setSelectorString("selectors");

        fixture.init(mock(FilterConfig.class));
        fixture.doFilter(request, response, mock(FilterChain.class));
        fixture.destroy();

        List<LoggingEvent> events = logger.getLoggingEvents();
        assertEquals(0, events.size());
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why it is failing with the ACS Commons version change?
This is like breaking lot many junit test classes

Comment: Did you find the issue?

Comment: We have same issue with                 
<artifactId>io.wcm.testing.aem-mock.junit5</artifactId>
<version>3.0.2</version>